# Send date to Template of django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

in my project, user after register can complete his information in another form. after completed this form and submitted it every time he visits this page, he sees the completed form. but i have a problem in this form, calender of user's birthday field works well at the first time when field is empty, but after the form is completed and submitting when the user wants to change it the calendar looks like this:

[image]

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ED_CHOICES = [
        ('hs', 'High school'),
        ('bc', 'Bachelor'),
        ('ms', 'Master'),
        ('do', 'Doctor'),
    ]
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    education = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ED_CHOICES)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

forms.py:

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ED_CHOICES = [
        ('hs', 'High school'),
        ('bc', 'Bachelor'),
        ('ms', 'Master'),
        ('do', 'Doctor'),
    ]

    phone = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'input--style-4'}),
        label=''
    )
    birthday = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'input--style-4 js-datepicker'}),
        label=''
    )
    education = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.Select(choices=ED_CHOICES, attrs={'class': 'select-dropdown'}),
        label=''
    )
    gender = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'radio-container m-r-45'}),
        label=''
    )

    class Meta:
        model = models.UserProfile
        fields = ['phone', 'birthday', 'education', 'gender']
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from . import forms, models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

my_user = get_user_model()
my_profile = models.UserProfile
first = True

def profile(request, slug):
    global first
    user = my_user.objects.get(username=slug)
    if first:
        pro_form = forms.ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    else:
        pro = my_profile.objects.get(user=user)
        pro_form = forms.ProfileForm(request.POST or None, instance=pro)
    form = forms.UserProfile(request.POST or None, instance=user)
    context = {'FORM': form, 'PRO': pro_form, 'USER': user}
    if form.is_valid() and pro_form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        pro = pro_form.save(commit=False)
        pro.user = user
        pro.save()
        first = False
        if 'gender' in request.POST:
            pro_form.gender = request.POST.get('gender')
        return redirect('HOME')
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)
```

template:

```
            <div class="row row-space">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <label class="label">Birthday</label>
                            <div class="input-group-icon">
                                {{ PRO.birthday }}
                                <i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-note input-icon js-btn-calendar"></i>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

js:

```
(function ($) {
    'use strict';
    /*==================================================================
        [ Daterangepicker ]*/
    try {
        $('.js-datepicker').daterangepicker({
            "singleDatePicker": true,
            "showDropdowns": true,
            "autoUpdateInput": false,
            locale: {
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            },
        });
    
        var myCalendar = $('.js-datepicker');
        var isClick = 0;
    
        $(window).on('click',function(){
            isClick = 0;
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('apply.daterangepicker',function(ev, picker){
            isClick = 0;
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
    
        });
    
        $('.js-btn-calendar').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
    
            if(isClick === 1) isClick = 0;
            else if(isClick === 0) isClick = 1;
    
            if (isClick === 1) {
                myCalendar.focus();
            }
        });
    
        $(myCalendar).on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            isClick = 1;
        });
    
        $('.daterangepicker').on('click',function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    
    
    } catch(er) {console.log(er);}
    /*[ Select 2 Config ]
        ===========================================================*/
    
    try {
        var selectSimple = $('.js-select-simple');
    
        selectSimple.each(function () {
            var that = $(this);
            var selectBox = that.find('select');
            var selectDropdown = that.find('.select-dropdown');
            selectBox.select2({
                dropdownParent: selectDropdown
            });
        });
    
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is likely an issue with your JavaScript and not Django. Can you share your `js-datepicker` code?

Comment: i put the js code above

Comment: at first when birthday field is blank, calendar works well

Comment: Note sure on your JS code, seems like a lot of code for a date picker. What you might want to check is the Django locale. Your Datepicker is set to 'DD/MM/YYYY', is your Django locale the same?